# jQuery JSON converting time values to numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with a JSON conversion by jQuery AJAX.

**Ajax Setup**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/get_available_schedule.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {field: field, day: day, hour: inicio},
})
```

I have this response from server

```
{"success":true,"ranges":[["22:00","22:30"],["22:30","23:00"],["01:30","02:00"],["02:00","02:30"]],"close":"03:30"}
```

But at the moment I do a 'console.log' of the response in the Ajax success, it will convert to this:

```
close: "03:30"
ranges: Array(2)
0: (2) [5400, 9000]
1: (2) [79200, 82800]
success: true
```

I don't know why the 'ranges' array are converted to numbers, I want that be likely the response, an array of 2 strings

I try to Google the problem but I don't find anything, or I don't know how to search it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `JSON.parse(...)` with your response string does not return the object you describe.

Comment: What exactly **is** the problem?  Given that the network console is already showing the response as an object, it's already being parsed, unless you're telling jQuery to treat the response as text and bypassing the auto parsing it will do in this case

Comment: Sorry guys, i edit the question. I need that sub arrays 'ranges' be an 'array' of strings, like the server response. Not an array of numbers

Comment: javascript json parsing isn't going to turn `["22:00","22:30"]` into `[5400, 9000]`.  it's just not going to happen.  Something else is going on here that you're not explaining to us

Comment: @Taplar yes, it be converted automatically, i literally log the response

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zk0sdvL7/  No, javascript json parsing does not convert strings to numbers

Comment: Something not quite right - your json has 4 items in the range, but your expanded object only has 2.  `ranges: Array(2)` - so it's not the same object generated from the provided json.

Comment: I had the same result as @Taplar, just in the console enter: `$.parseJSON('{"success":true,"ranges":[["22:00","22:30"],["22:30","23:00"],["01:30","02:00"],["02:00","02:30"]],"close":"03:30"}')`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GSDxbhl line 290. I don't know why this happen here, in other project I use the same and works fine :/

Comment: This may be an issue with the object being logged in the console changing, and the user not looking in the console until after it is changed.  I know there exists a duplicate about this

Comment: Rather than a console.log(), put `debugger;` there and inspect the element

Comment: You could also change it to `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))` to make it console log an object that is completely disconnected from the original that may change.

Comment: You are right, if I quit the 'if' statement its work fine, but I don't change the response var there, why this happen? https://imgur.com/a/Vw5gIq5

Comment: `disabled_hours` references the same array as the original element.  So if anything changes the contents of that array, it's going to affect the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `disabled_hours` var in `timepicker` library option declared later in the code.

It changes the value of `disabled_hours`, and I can't looking in the console until after it is changed.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/get_available_schedule.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {field: field, day: day, hour: inicio},
})
.done(function(dataSCHEDULE) {
  console.log(dataSCHEDULE);
  // debugger;
  if (dataSCHEDULE.success) {
    disabled_hours  = dataSCHEDULE.ranges;
    console.log(disabled_hours);
    close_hour      = dataSCHEDULE.close;
  }
  else {
    console.warn('API ERROR -> Getting available hours');
  }
})
.fail(function(error) {
  console.error('API ERROR -> Getting available hours');
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I've seen a duplicate for this, but I can't find it at the moment, so here goes.

```js
var data = { ranges: [ "A", "B", "C" ] };

//log the data element to the console
console.log( data );

//set the anotherVariable to point to the ranges array
//this does NOT create a separate element
//both variables point to the same array in memory
var anotherVariable = data.ranges;

//this changes both variables, because as said before, they point to the
//same array
anotherVariable[1] = "weee";

/*

If you look at your actual browser, you will see that the consoled
data has ranges of "A", "weee", "C".  This is because your browser
is showing you the value of the element, up to date.  Not only of
when you logged it.

*/
```

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but nope. Here is the unique place that define and use `disabled hours` http://jsfiddle.net/cp2kor3y/

Comment: The `timepicker` library option was the problem, I don't know why, but it changes the array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EmanuelM. please add an answer that answers your question. Upvote this by all means, but anyone will a similar problem will not get an answer from this and will likely miss your comment of the actual problem.  You could also update the title to make it clearer/easier to find in future (without stating the solution).

Comment: @freedomn-m ready, but I don't know how to name the problem, and I can't vote or accept my own answer :(